# How to compare Entity framework Any() with lower comparing objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sonarqube

There is a code block in our project like this.
But this block causing SonarQube error:

> Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity

So I need to reduce logical operators. But this block checking db if there is a record. But for checking record it comparing too many objects.

So, is there any way to reduce this and make it more effiency?

```
if (applicantsForThisApplication != null && applicantsForThisApplication.Any(a => a.ApplicationId == item.ApplicationId && a.FirstName.Equals(item.FirstName) && a.MiddleName.Equals(item.MiddleName)
    && a.LastName.Equals(item.LastName) && (a.MobilePhone != null && (item.MobilePhone != null ? a.MobilePhone.Equals(item.MobilePhone) : false))
    && a.CreatedBy.Equals(item.CreatedBy) && (a.EmailAddress != null && (item.EmailAddress != null ? a.EmailAddress.Equals(item.EmailAddress) : false))))
{
    var existingApplicationSignatory = applicantsForThisApplication.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ApplicationId == item.ApplicationId && a.FirstName.Equals(item.FirstName) && a.MiddleName.Equals(item.MiddleName)
    && a.LastName.Equals(item.LastName) && (a.MobilePhone != null && (item.MobilePhone != null ? a.MobilePhone.Equals(item.MobilePhone) : false))
    && a.CreatedBy.Equals(item.CreatedBy) && (a.EmailAddress != null && (item.EmailAddress != null ? a.EmailAddress.Equals(item.EmailAddress) : false)));

    //other jobs...
}
```

Comment: Which database are you using? What's the actual query? Right now it's hard to understand what this very long condition does or even if it makes sense. `Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity` is pretty accurate. Using the ternary operator in this case makes things a lot harder to read.  Is `a` the entity or a parameter object? What about `item`? Case-sensitivity depends on the column's collation. So does indexing. If you want good performance, you need a case-insensitive index, otherwise the database will have to scan the entire table to look for matches

Comment: As for `item.MobilePhone != null ? a.MobilePhone.Equals(item.MobilePhone) : false`, why? What is this supposed to do? If you want to ignore a parameter, just don't use that parameter. You can chain `.Where()` clauses to construct the equivalent of `AND` conditions dynamically, eg `if (phone!=null){ query=query.Where(x=>x.Phone==phone)`. [Catch-all queries](https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) that try to generate `AND (@phone IS NULL OR @phone=phone)` result in bad execution plans and bad performance

Comment: BTW where's EF in all this code? Is `applicantsForThisApplication` a DbSet or query? Is this code executing the same query twice, once to check for existence and once to retrieve the same data? Why not execute `FirstOrAsync` only then?

Comment: Hello actually its not my code. I'm working on this for refactor it and pass sonarqube scan. Its using mssql. and this block is checking if there is a record in table. For that it compares all entity object with table column. So basicly is there anyway to compare fewer object like compare entity itself not columns?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos
applicantsForThisApplication is a query. thats a list comes from ef query.

Comment: So maybe get item with FirstorDefault and check if its null. I think it will reduce double checking to single.

Comment: A list is not a query. A list is data already loaded on the client. What's the actual type of `applicantsForThisApplication` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity

SonarQube got that right. It's hard to understand what this long piece of code does. It seems to be executing the same query twice to return the same data. It also seems to be trying to create a [catch-all query](https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) that either compares a field with a parameter or ignores the parameter if it's null. Such queries result in bad execution plans and aren't needed at all when using LINQ.

Assuming `applicantsForThisApplication` is an actual EF query then:

1. `applicantsForThisApplication !=null` shouldn't be needed
2. The conditions can be constructed dynamically.
3. A single call to `FindAsync` is enough. If there's no match, the result will be null

In LINQ, each operator returns a *new* query. It's possible to chain `Where` conditions one after the other to create the equivalent of multiple `AND` conditions, eg :

```
//Add the required conditions
var query = applicantsForThisApplication.Where(a => 
    a.ApplicationId == item.ApplicationId && 
    a.FirstName == item.FirstName && 
    a.MiddleName == item.MiddleName &&
    ...
    a.LastName  == item.LastName);

//Add optional conditions
if (item.MobilePhone!=null)
{
    query = query.Where(a=> a.MobilePhone == item.MobilePhone);
}
if (item.EmailAddress != null)
{
    query = query.Where(a=>a.EmailAddress == item.EmailAddress);
}

var applicant=query.FirstOrDefalut();
```

There's no need to check the table field for null. In SQL NULL matches nothing, not even NULL so any comparison with NULL fails directly.

I separated the required from the optional conditions, and put each condition in a separate line intentionally so I can read what's being compared. Putting everything in a single long line has no benefits but does make the code a lot harder to read and maintain

For example, while trying to find the optional parameters I noticed `a.CreatedBy.Equals(item.CreatedBy)` between two optional parameters `EmailAddress` and `MobilePhone`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i would extract following block of code into separate methods:

```
    private bool CheckSomeItems(object a, object item) 
    {
        return a.ApplicationId == item.ApplicationId && a.FirstName.Equals(item.FirstName) && a.MiddleName.Equals(item.MiddleName)
        && a.LastName.Equals(item.LastName);
    }

    private bool CheckMobile(object a, object item)
    {
        return a.MobilePhone != null && item.MobilePhone != null && a.MobilePhone.Equals(item.MobilePhone);
    }

    private bool CheckMail(object a, object item)
    {
        return a.EmailAddress != null && item.EmailAddress != null && a.EmailAddress.Equals(item.EmailAddress);
    }
```

and your code becomes:

```
if (applicantsForThisApplication != null && applicantsForThisApplication.Any(a => CheckSomeItems(a, item) && CheckMobile(a, item) && a.CreatedBy.Equals(item.CreatedBy) && CheckMail(a, item)))
{
    var existingApplicationSignatory = applicantsForThisApplication.FirstOrDefault(a => CheckSomeItems(a, item) && CheckMobile(a, item) && a.CreatedBy.Equals(item.CreatedBy) && CheckMail(a, item));

    //other jobs...
}
```

Comment: You can't use client-side methods in an EF LINQ query. LINQ queries get translated to SQL. If the parameter is null there's no reason to include a condition anyway